# merging same structured xml with total on attribute using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I Hvae two xml of same structure , I just want the sum of attribute in final xml. Like in below input1.xml and input2.xml atribute dataset has value 20 and input2 has value 30 so output.xml should have value=50

input1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chart xmlns=" "
       labelStep="1"
       showValues="0"
       anchorRadius="1"
      >
   <categories>
      <category Label="Technical RATH"/>
      <category Label="Technical RATH2"/>
   </categories>
   <dataset>
      <set value="20" color="a5cf5a"/>
      <set value="10" color="b5cf5a"/>
   </dataset>
</chart>
```

input2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chart xmlns=" "
       labelStep="1"
       showValues="0"
       anchorRadius="1"
      >
   <categories>
      <category Label="Technical RATH"/>
      <category Label="Technical RATH2"/>
   </categories>
   <dataset>
      <set value="30" color="a5cf5a"/>
      <set value="150" color="b5cf5a"/>
   </dataset>
</chart>
```

and output.xml should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chart xmlns=" "
       labelStep="1"
       showValues="0"
       anchorRadius="1"
      >
   <categories>
      <category Label="Technical RATH"/>
      <category Label="Technical RATH2"/>
   </categories>
   <dataset>
      <set value="50" color="a5cf5a"/>
      <set value="160" color="b5cf5a"/>
   </dataset>
</chart>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to fix up what is going on with your namespaces in these documents and adapt the below to suit, but leaving that aside, you can do this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="set/@value">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="number(.) + number(document('source2.xml')/chart/dataset/set/@value)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I was trying this on @smj '<set value="0" anchorRadius="2" anchorBorderThickness="3"/>
   <set value="0" anchorRadius="2" anchorBorderThickness="3"/>' how to set both value if we have source2.xml with same tags ,I ma trying for- each but not getting results

Comment: i tried using for each on node in first xml but getting the correct output, i feel it not reading the second xml file

Comment: I am doing like this '<xsl:template match="dataset">
   <xsl:for-each select="set/@value">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(number(.), document('file2.xml')/chart/dataset/set/@value)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>'